# Django "Instance" Form Fields Not Rendering

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a dynamic form that will allow multiple inputs and increase the size of the form as needed.

Here's a simplified version of my form.

```
class Email(django.forms.Form):
  givenName = django.forms.CharField(label='First Name:', max_length=100, required=True)

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    e = kwargs.pop('num_emails', 1)
    super(Email, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for i in xrange(e):
      self.fields['email_%i' % i] = django.forms.EmailField(label='Email:', required=False)

  def iter_email(self):
    for k, v in sorted(self.fields.items()):
      if k.startswith('email_'):
        yield v
```

Then, the template

```
<form input action="/email"method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="editor-field">{{ form.givenName.label_tag }}{{ form.givenName }}</div>
    {% for m in form.iter_email %}
    <div class="editor-field">{{ m.label_tag }}{{ m }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

When I browse to this form, the email fields are not showing up properly. (The givenName field works properly.) I just get these strings printed in HTML based on the specified `num_emails`.

`<django.forms.fields.EmailField object at 0x7f7d100ebcd0>`

I have also tried `yield`ing `v.widget`, but that just shows

`<django.forms.widgets.TextInput object at 0x7f54e00f23d0>`

I feel like I just need to modify what `iter_email()` yields, but I couldn't figure it out by examining that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form.fields` holds the fields themselves, what you want for rendering are the BounFields that you can get directly from the form itself, ie:

```
def iter_email(self):
    for k in sorted(self.fields.keys()):
        if k.startswith('email_'):
            yield self[k]
```